# mongodb group by a field and count all from a field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to fix this little issue, i have trying to search a round to find help, but i can't find help anywhere so i trying to ask here.

i try to get a top most views products from a visitor log, the data in my mongodb look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56617f12cc8eaaa6010041ab"),
    "Product" : {
        "UUID" : "c7b3e23e-0bf9-4fd5-b8d3-f559b80c42ed"
    },
    "Log" : {
        "Method" : "visit",
        "IP" : "127.0.0.1",
        "Added" : "2015-12-04 12:54:58"
    }
}
```

What i want is create a group by on the Product.UUID field and all logs not older then 1,5 month and what i have done right now look like this.

```
db.getCollection('log-product').aggregate([
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id:"$Product.UUID",
            total: {$sum : 1}
        }
     },
    {"$sort" : {total: -1}},
    {"$limit" : 8}
])
```

here i group on Product.UUID and sort it DESC on total count and limit it to 8, my problem is i can't find a way to count how many visitor the single product have.

Hope somebody out there can help me width this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter "Log.Added" by time interval first then pass the results to $group:

```
db.getCollection('log-product').aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "Log.Added": { $gt: new Date(2015,10, 15), $lt: new Date(2015,11,15) }
            }   
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                _id:"$Product.UUID",
                total: {$sum : 1}
            }
         },
        {"$sort" : {total: -1}},
        {"$limit" : 8}
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by Log.Added and group by product uuid and $Log.IP.:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * 45;

var initInterval = new Date(new Date() - dateOffset);
db.getCollection('log-product').aggregate([
        { "$match" : { "Log.Added": {$lte: currentDate, $gte: initInterval}}},
        {
            "$group" : {
                _id:{"product": "$Product.UUID", "visitor":"$Log.IP"},
                total: {$sum : 1}
            }
         },
        {"$sort" : {total: -1}},
        {"$limit" : 8}
    ])
```

Comment: i need to count how maney products there are in a time interval and return the number and sort it after and ofc only output 8 products.